# What is causing the error "Return Type 'TableRow' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by method 'build'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an App in Flutter/Dart and I'm currently working on the layout of the App. I'm trying to create a standart Table Layout, which works perfectly, up until I want to outsource the code into different files. At this point I created a class extending StatelessWidget which overrides the built method returning a TableRow. At this point my IDE claims that 'TableRow' is not of type 'Widget'.

I tried using different approaches like Grid Layout and some tricks with Rows/Columns, but not a single one is actually the solution I'm searching for. I'm just trying to refactor the code into multiple files.

This code is now in a seperate file. While the TableRow was a direct child in the Table() it worked perfectly fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TableRow(
            children: [
                TableCell(
                    child: Text("test"),
                ),
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

The file I'd call the method from would somewhat look like this:

```
Container(
     constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 300),
     child: Table(
         children: [
             Test(),
             Test(),
             Test(),
             Test(),
         ],
     ),
 ),
```

I simply expected the TableRow to be recognized as a normal Widget as everything else is. TableCell for example is recognized as Widget. The error Message I get is "error: The return type 'TableRow' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by the method 'build'. (return_of_invalid_type at [projectname] lib/widgets/auth/shared/test.dart:12)". The error happens before compiling and gets marked by Android Studio.

Edit: Added code call

Comment: Is this exact code you are using? You are missing the 'child' parameter for the TableCell.

Comment: Hi, no it's not, sorry. I edited it into the original post so it makes more sense now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I see, can you explain your reasoning for this? Why do you want a tablerow widget, when you could just have a simple method that returns a tablerow?

Comment: I wanted to follow the "Everything is a Widget"-kind of design. Basically creating a Widget for everything that holds information. In my code there is a constructor holding additional values, for example the text that would be written instead of "test". I just wanted to simplify the code for better understanding.

Comment: I understand, I would say this would be taking it a step too far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message tells you what's wrong: `TableRow` isn't a `Widget`.

If you look at the [`TableRow` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TableRow-class.html), note that there is no "Inheritance" section that shows that it derives from `Widget`.

If you look at the [`Table` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html), note that `children` is a `List<TableRow>` and *not* a `List<Widget>`.

"Everything is a widget" is a hyperbole meant to get people to think of decomposing their UIs into composable widgets. Obviously there are some things that aren't `Widget`s (`int`, `String`, `Function`, `Element`, `RenderObject`, ...).