# How to make reusable inheritance of TableRow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was wondering, why my IDE gives me error `A value of type 'TableRow' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget' dart(return_of_invalid_type)`.

Then I found that TableRow isn't a widget within this post [What is causing the error "Return Type 'TableRow' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by method 'build'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693424/what-is-causing-the-error-return-type-tablerow-isnt-a-widget-as-defined-b).

Then how can I efficiently write code like widget does ?
I have bunch of TableRow that each piece has conditional statement.

Or is there any recommended package or solution that could I use to make similar things like Table does ?
In this case, I used Table to make indented pair text key and value to be more visually clean.

Best regards, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of TableRow and add each table row to that list. Add a table and then assign the list to its children parameter. TableRow doesn't inherit a widget and hence cannot be returned as a Widget.